# Enviar una varible de Javascript a Node.JS

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs

tengo lo siguiente en Node.JS:

```
app.get('/datos/', (req, res)=>{
  var dato1 = "Hola";
  console.log(dato1)
});
```

En mi archivo de Javascript, tengo una variable que dice `var dato2="Mundo"`. Me gustaría saber como puedo pasar ese valor de dato2 que es "Mundo" a mi servidor de Node.JS y allí guardarlo en una variable para poder imprimir desde la consola en Node.JS quedando algo así:

```
console.log(dato1,dato2);
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: la variable la pasas por la URL?

Comment: Sí. En mi archivo de Javascript tengo la varible dato2 con lo de Mundo y necesito que ese valor de "mundo" la pueda pasar a Node.JS

Comment: y si pruebas asi: `app.get('/datos/:dato', (req, res)=>{
  var dato1 = req.params.dato
  console.log(dato1)
});`

Comment: El título es un poco confuso: NodeJS es un intérprete de Javascript. No debería el título algo como *Cómo enviar datos desde el navegador a mi servidor NodeJS*?

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema se divide en varias partes, que voy a intentar abordar:

1. **¿Cómo obtener peticiones en un servidor basado en Node.JS?**

   Vamos a suponer que estas usando [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/es/) para obtener peticiones a la dirección `/datos/` de tu aplicación servidora. Tu código actúa de `endpoint`. Para recibir una petición debes enviarla desde un cliente. Vamos a suponer también que lo estas ejecutando en local y que no hay ninguna ruta definida ni has cambiado el puerto por defecto de expressjs. Por tanto, el `endpoint` que has definido para esa función sería `http://localhsot:3000/datos/`.
   La función que usas, `get`, define el [método de petición http](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) que debe usarse para alcanzar esta función o este `endpoint`. Como es un GET, accediendo a esta url desde un navegador obtendrías en el terminal "Hola", ya que se ejecuta tu función. A la función que estas utilizando le pasas otra que defines tu, en forma de función flecha, con dos parámetros de entrada, `req` y `res`. Estos parámetros representan la **req**uest y la **res**ponse (en español, petición y respuesta). En el parámetro `req` tendras por tanto toda la información sobre la petición que se ha realizado, y en el parámetro `res` podras establecer toda la información sobre la respuesta que deseas dar a la petición. En tu caso, el navegador quedaría "colgado", ya que no envías respuesta alguna a esta petición. Lo normal sería que le dieras una respuesta, al menos para decir que todo ha ido bien (o con el error que se ha producido en caso contrario). Por tanto, lo mínimo correcto sería poner `res.sendStatus(200)` al final de tu función (equivalente a `res.status(200).send('OK')`).
2. **¿Cómo enviar peticiones desde un cliente a este servidor?**

   Centrándonos sólo en el método GET, una forma de hacer esto es simplemente accediendo desde el navegador como hemos dicho antes. Otra es, como propones, lanzando una petición desde un código javascript ejecutado en cliente. De nuevo, hay muchas formas de hacer esto desde javascript, pero como no nos has proporcionado más información voy a suponer que en cliente usas javascript vanilla sin ningún framework, sin jQuery ni nada. Para hacer una petición desde javascript puedes usar la clase `XMLHttpRequest` como se explica en [esta pregunta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript):

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Esta función propuesta tiene dos parámetros, una para la URL que quieres alcanzar, y otro para proporcionar una función con lo que realizar al recibir la respuesta del servidor. En tu caso, si quieres ignorar la respuesta y simplemente enviar la petición, podríamos simplificar la función a algo así:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

3. **¿Cómo enviar parámetros en la petición?**

   Para una petición de un método GET, los parámetros van en la misma URL, por lo que es tan sencillo como concatenar con el formato apropiado la variable que quieres enviar. Volviendo al caso que estamos desarrollando, la url que quieres enviar es `http://localhsot:3000/datos/?dato2=mundo`. La interrogación indica que comienzan los parámetros, con el nombre del parámetro primero, un signo `=` y el valor del parámetro. Para añadir más parámetros, cada nuevo parámetro debe ir separado con el signo `&`. Por tanto, usando la función anterior:

```
var dato2 = 'mundo';
var endpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/datos/';
var theUrl = endpoint + '?dato2=' + dato2;
httpGetAsync(theUrl);
```

4. **¿Cómo procesar estos parámetros en el servidor?**

   Ahora ya tenemos en nuestro servidor el parámetro. Se encontrará, como nombramos en el primer punto, dentro de la variable `req`. Como hemos enviado el parámetro en la propia url, lo podremos encontrar dentro del objeto `query` de `req`, por lo que `console.log(dato1, req.query.dato2);` te daría como resultado `Holamundo`.

Hay otras maneras de hacerlo. Por ejemplo, como propone en un comentario a tu respuesta [@shadow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/75901/shadow), puedes usar parte de la url como parámetro del endpoint en vez de enviarlo como parámetro de la petición. En ese caso, la url a formar sería directamente `http://localhost:3000/datos/mundo`, la url de tu función get `'/datos/:dato2'` y la forma de acceder al parámetro sería a través del objeto params en vez del objeto query, `console.log(dato1, req.params.dato2);`

Espero que esta respuesta te ayude a entender un poco mejor como funciona de forma básica el sistema que estas construyendo.

Answer (score 0):

Guarda variables de este tipo en un js file en tu servidor, y importalas de tal manera:

```
const datos2 = require("./variables.js")
```

O igual hasta puedes asegurarla guardandola como una 
Variable ambiental (ENV Variable) y accesarlas de tal modo:

```
process.env.datos2
```

ya que si lo que buscas es en verdad obtenerlas por medio del browser en una URL, entonces tendras que pasarla por el objeto *request* que viene siendo tu peticion. Me parece que estas usando Express entonces seria de tal forma:

```
app.get('/datos/:datos', (req, res)=>{
  var dato1 = req.params.datos;
  console.log(dato1)
});
```